# Google Cloud SQL API options to monitor the instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

We are trying to monitor the Cloud SQL instance programmatically but we were not able to find any API to fetch the metrics like CPU usage and storage information that is available through the console. Also, we would like to monitor the Error and Query logs of the SQL instance using the API.

Can anyone please help us by pointing in the right direction or if there is any workaround that we can use?

Comment: Hi @Saksham, just out of interest, why don't the stackdriver metrics such as /database/cpu/utilisation work for your case - per the docs at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-cloudsql).

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Stackdriver API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-cloudsql) with which you can retrieve details about the CPU usage and storage information. There is also the [Stackdriver Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/) for your logs.